# My Microsoft Access Append Query (VBA and SQL) works for a literal, but not for a variable

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

This is Microsoft Access, VBA and SQL related.

In VBA I make this SQL statement (see below) and run it.  This correctly appends to testTable. (The field in testTable is Date/Time and it has format 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss')

```
sql = "INSERT INTO testTable (DateOpen) VALUES ('12/01/2021 12:13:14')
```

However, when I do this (below), the code prompts me with a "Enter Parameter Value" for dateVar. Why?  I just told it what dateVar was in the SQL.:

```
DIM dateVar as string

dateVar = "12/01/2021 12:13:14"

sql = "INSERT INTO testTable (DateOpen) VALUES (dateVar)
```

When I add quotes (see below) the code does not prompt me with an Enter Parameter Value msgbox.
I get a msgbox that says You Are About To Append. But when it tries to append it fails with "Microsoft Access Can't Append the Records" due to a "type conversion error"

```
DIM dateVar as string

dateVar = "12/01/2021 12:13:14"

sql = "INSERT INTO testTable (DateOpen) VALUES ('dateVar')
```

Help Please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concatenation of the `dateVar` variable into the SQL string needs to be fixed:

```vb
Dim dateVar as string

dateVar = "12/01/2021 12:13:14"

sql = "INSERT INTO testTable (DateOpen) VALUES ('" & dateVar & "')"
```

If you're having problem building your SQL then `Debug.Print sql` will let you see what's actually getting executed.

Comment: Worked.  Thanks Tim.